# The relationship between dll and rdlc

Tags: c#, rdlc

Can anyone tell me what is the relationship between dll and rdlc.
Every time, when I publish website,  it give me dll. 
why do we need to have dll for rdlc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First DLL files are Dynamic Linked Libraries While RDLC files are reports of SSRS.
When publishing a C#.net project containing RDLC (SSRS Report), the .net exports some DLLs of Report Viewer, those DLLs are necessary to view reports definied in RDLC file.

Answer (score 0):

A .dll is a *Dynamically Linked Library* of executable code. An RDLC file, if I'm understanding correctly, is a client-side report definition file used by SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). These are generally XML files that define the structure of a report, and thus are not executable. Your website executable is compiled into the DLL, and the RDLC serves as the report definition.

Apologies in advance if RDLC is referring to some other technology.